# Extinction probability of a simple birth death process

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

X is a simple birth death process with birth rate $\lambda n$ and death rate $\mu n$
Embedded within a simple birth death process is a simple random walk.
Let $Y_n $ be the value of X at the time of the nth event. 
$Y_0=X_0=1 $

Then

$Y_{n+1} = Y_n + 1 $ with probability $\lambda / (\lambda + \mu)$

And

$Y_{n+1} = Y_n-1 $ with probability $\mu / (\lambda + \mu)$

Provided $Y_n > 0$

Since X doesn't explode, extinction occurs in finite time iff $Y_n =0, n<\infty$

So $P[Y_n =0, n<\infty]. =  1$ if $\mu\geq\lambda$
Or $(\mu/\lambda)^X_0 $ if $\mu<\lambda$

where we use our analysis of discrete-time simple random walks,

How is the analysis of discrete simple random walks used here, I don't understand where these probabilities come from, how are they worked out?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I  would use branching process (which is discrete-time random walk) to solve this problem.

According to your description, an individual "gives birth to" $2$ individuals with the probability $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}$; an individual "gives birth to" $0$ individuals with the probability $\frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}$.

This gives the generating function $$G(s) = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} + \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}s^2$$.

Extinction probability is the smaller root of the function
$$s = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} + \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}s^2$$.

After calculation, the equation has two roots: $1$, $\frac{\mu}{\lambda} $.

Indeed, if $\frac{\mu}{\lambda} \geq 1$, i.e. $\mu \geq \lambda$, the population will go extinct within a finite time( [ =$0$ , <∞].=$1$ )